# Unity3d AudioSource not creatable

Tags: c#, audio, unity-game-engine

I have a strange problem in unity3d.
I want to use several audio sources for playing a sound with a overlapping effect. Because I can't explain the problem myself- I tried the same with only one AudioSource.
So I have this script:

```
 public class audioOverlap:MonoBehaviour
 {
    private AudioSource sct;
    public AudioClip clp;
    void Start(){
       sct=new AudioSource(); 
       sct.clip=clp;//NullReferenceException!?
    } 
 }
```

Because of the NullReferenceException- I tried figuring out why.

```
    void Start(){
       sct=new AudioSource(); 
       if(sct==null){Debug.Log("AudioSourceBug");/*gets executed-wtf???*/}
       if(clp==null){Debug.Log("AudioClipBug");/*gets notexecuted-okay*/}
       sct.clip=clp;//NullReferenceException!?
    }
```

I know what a NullReferenceException is-please don't mark it as duplicate when the linked question isn't a working solution:

- [Yes-I've read this question...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

I'm a beginner with Unity, but not with C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is perfectly natural C#, but it won't fly:

```
sct=new AudioSource();
```

Unity has a component-driven, factory-based architecture. Instead of calling a component constructor, Unity wants you to call [`AddComponent`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.AddComponent.html) to attach the component to a specific `GameObject`:

```
sct = gameObject.AddComponent<AudioSource>();
```

There are a few reasons for that. First off, Unity needs every `Component` to be owned by a `GameObject`. Second, many of Unity's built-in classes are actually shells representing resources that are created and managed by the engine's underlying native code layer.

Comment: I really wasn't far of going postal because I didn't understood this problem... 

They really should have made the class `sealed` (or is there a reason not to?). Thank you very much.

Comment: @leAthlon I've also wondered why they have public constructors if we're not supposed to use them. So far, I don't know, but I hope there's a reason.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried adding the audioSource to another object (like a child object)?
maybe the problem is having to audio sources on one object.